# DocuSign Folder::listItems API's output does not include envelopes

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using Laravel 7 and added DocuSign PHP SDK and Laravel wrapper:

```
public function getFolderItems($folderId)
{
    $folderApi = new FoldersApi($this->apiClient);
    return $folderApi->listItems($this->accountId, $folderId);
}
```

For example, I called this method to get envelopes in the `Draft` folder. The result is:

```
{
    "endPosition": "0",
    "folders": [
        {
            "folderId": "...",
            "hasSubFolders": "false",
            "itemCount": "1",
            "name": "Draft",
            "owner": {
                "email": "...@gmail.com",
                "userId": "...",
                "userName": "P. K."
            },
            "subFolderCount": "0",
            "type": "draft",
            "uri": "/folders/..."
        }
    ],
    "resultSetSize": "1",
    "startPosition": "0",
    "totalSetSize": "1"
}
```

**Note:** Some data in this result hide with `...`.

But as we can see on [this link](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/folders/folders/listitems/) (DocuSign REST API) the response should be something like this:

```
{
  "resultSetSize": "sample string 1",
  "startPosition": "sample string 2",
  "endPosition": "sample string 3",
  "totalSetSize": "sample string 4",
  "previousUri": "sample string 5",
  "nextUri": "sample string 6",
  "folderItems": [
    {
      "ownerName": "sample string 1",
      "envelopeId": "sample string 2",
      "envelopeUri": "sample string 3",
      "status": "sample string 4",
      "senderName": "sample string 5",
      "senderEmail": "sample string 6",
      "createdDateTime": "sample string 7",
      "sentDateTime": "sample string 8",
      "completedDateTime": "sample string 9",
      "subject": "sample string 10",
      "templateId": "sample string 11",
      "name": "sample string 12",
      "shared": "sample string 13",
      "password": "sample string 14",
      "description": "sample string 15",
      "lastModified": "sample string 16",
      "pageCount": 17,
      "uri": "sample string 18",
      "is21CFRPart11": "sample string 19",
      "isSignatureProviderEnvelope": "sample string 20",
      "customFields": [
        {
          "fieldId": "sample string 1",
          "name": "sample string 2",
          "show": "sample string 3",
          "required": "sample string 4",
          "value": "sample string 5",
          "configurationType": "sample string 6",
          "errorDetails": {
            "errorCode": "sample string 1",
            "message": "sample string 2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the `include_items` parameter.

From the reference doc you linked: *Indicates whether folder items are included in the response. If this parameter is omitted, the default is false.*

In the PHP SDK, I believe this means you will need to create a ListItemsOptions object, populate it by setting the include_items param to true and apply it to your request.